# How to test angularJs http request jsonp

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jsonp, karma-jasmine, httpbackend

So, i am trying to follow [this tutorial](http://www.toptal.com/angular-js/a-step-by-step-guide-to-your-first-angularjs-app) while trying to create some unit tests along the way.

Well i am stuck at trying to test the $http request to the ergast developer api. As u can see in the tutorial the $http request is made to the service *ergastAPIservice*

```
angular.module('F1FeederApp.services', []).
factory('ergastAPIservice', function($http) {
    var ergastAPI = {};
    ergastAPI.getDrivers = function() {
        return $http({
            method: 'JSONP',
            url: 'http://ergast.com/api/f1/2013/driverStandings.json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK'
        });
    }
    return ergastAPI;
});
```

---

**Which is then used in the controller:**

```
angular.module('F1FeederApp.controllers', []).
controller('driversController', function($scope, ergastAPIservice) {
    $scope.nameFilter = null;
    $scope.driversList = [];
    ergastAPIservice.getDrivers().success(function (response) {
        $scope.driversList = response.MRData.StandingsTable.StandingsLists[0].DriverStandings;
    });
});
```

---

**How would i go about testing this (the service). I have started up something like this:**

---

```
  describe('F1FeederApp services', function() {
    describe('ergastAPIservice', function(){
        var scope, ctrl, $httpBackend;
        beforeEach(module('F1FeederApp'));
        beforeEach(inject(function(_$httpBackend_, $rootScope, $controller) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            ctrl = $controller('driversController', {$scope: scope});
            $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
            $httpBackend.whenJSONP("
            http://ergast.com/api/f1/2013/driverStandings.json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK").
                respond(WHAT SHOULD GO HERE);
        }));
        it("should get ???", function () {
            $httpBackend.flush();
            expect(WHAT SHOULD GO HERE).toEqual('foo');
        });
    });});
```

---

Like i said stuck,getting this to work, i thought that what ever you put in the respond should be what u expect in your test, that it doesn't have anything to do with the actual mocked $http request...or am i getting this all wrong

**Any tips and/or pointing me in the right direction would be very appreciated,**

***Cheers!***